# Postman: How to validate a response to have a correct date format

Tags: postman

Just can´t find how to validate the response to be in a date format like: 2014-07-14T21:15:58+00:00

pm.test("Validate dateCreated", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].dateCreated == ("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")); // timestamp

});

This is my awfull aproach, it validates the result even if I change operators or the date format in the assertion,I tried with $timestamp, and other examples here, but none seems to work please help, thx

The response body is like this

{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "rn": "1",
            "id": 2,
            "mxrId": null,
            "dateCreated": "2014-07-14T21:15:58+00:00",
            "dateModified": "2018-03-16T21:15:13+00:00",
            "svsId": "1",
            "token": "08A96E05",
            "name": "Original Test",
            "clientId": 1675,
            "projectId": 1,

Answer (score 1):

And this is what i came with, if you find a better way, please let me know.

let dateFormat = /([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/;

pm.test("Validate dateCreated", function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].dateCreated).to.match(dateFormat);

});

Comment: added time (zulu variant): /^([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]Z$)/